# Python: js code not updating in flask

Tags: python, flask

I am refreshing my browser...after running but,
changes are not affected in browser

```
from flask import Flask, send_file, render_template, send_file
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return send_file('templates/create_conf_view.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=1672,threaded=True)
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code you need to have a directory structure as follows:

```
app
|_
  run.py
  templates/
     |_create_conf_view.html
```

According to [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates) you should not pass `templates` when rendering a template.

Change your original file to and see if it works:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('create_conf_view.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=1672, thread=True)
```

Also be sure to access your application at specified port!